# http post - pass a javascript object to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a javascript object containing a string and a jstring to a mvc controller. This is my code and I am getting null value in the controller.
Thank you in advance for the help.

```
 function setMultiQuestion(question, responses) {
 qaObject = new questionAnswerObj('q', [{'correct':true,'answer':'A1'},   {'correct':true,'answer':'A2'}];);

 $http.post(baseUrl + "Admin/insertMultiAnswers", { qaObject: qaObject })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  })
  .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
  });
}

public ActionResult insertMultiAnswers(string[] qaObject)
{
    Console.Write(qaObject);
}
```

Comment: What properties does `qaObject`? If you create a class in C# (server side) with the same properties then you can make that type the input parameters for your POST Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send a string to server. Please use this:

```
$http.post(baseUrl + "Admin/insertMultiAnswers", { qaObject: JSON.stringify(qaObject) })
```

**JSON.stringify function turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores it in a string.**

See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your parameter to dynamic

```
  public ActionResult insertMultiAnswers(string[] qaObject)
```

to

```
  public ActionResult insertMultiAnswers(dynamic qaObject)
```